# "This man is called also "the bird" or "This man is also called "the bird"?

Tags: sentence-structure

Are the two following sentences are alike or just one of them is correct? 
Context: I'm trying to say that this man in addition to his real name (Josh for example), he is called in addition by us "the bird" because he has voice like bird.

> 1) "This man **is called also** "the bird"
>
> 2) "This man **is also called** "the bird"

Comment: There are two possible meanings for #2, but without additional context to disambiguate, it's impossible to say with any certainty which is intended. A) One man is known as the fastest, say, and also as the strongest. B) Two men have been called the strongest, e.g. they are competing for the title "World's Strongest Man".  Let's see who wins the competition. #1 is not ambiguous. It means the man is called something other than the strongest, as well as the strongest.

Comment: Thank you. I edited the question to make it clearer. II hope that now it's understood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option #2 is **correct**. Option 1 is **wrong**; it would mean the man's nickname is "Also The Bird".

The rules for where "also" belongs in a sentence are specific to it. There is an excellent list of these rules at [the EnglishPage.com page on "also"](http://www.englishpage.com/minitutorials/also.html).

It is true that Option 2 has two possible meanings, but that doesn't make it wrong. (Being ambiguous doesn't make a construction invalid or incorrect.) In comparison, Option 1 sounds unnatural because it doesn't follow the rules for the placement of "also". It is hard to imagine a good writer, or even just a casual speaker, using Option 1.

**Edit:** As ColleenV noted in the comment, the rules for the placement of "also" are essentially:

1. With single-word forms of *to be*, "also" come after the verb. E.g., "I am also in town."
2. With multiple-word forms of verbs, "also" usually comes in between. E.g., "I have also visited that city"; "She will also be singing a solo"; "We have also seen Paris"; "You will also have noted the exam is next week."
3. With regular single-word verbs, "also" usually comes before the verb. E.g., "He also enjoys cooking."

Comment: +1 for including a reference. It might be worthwhile to explain the rule about placing also after "to be" from the page you linked, just in case the link goes dead in the future.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22was%20called%20also%20the%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl

Comment: @TRomano Those are all pretty old texts, but it does bring up the point that it's grammatical even though it's old fashioned

Answer (score 2):

**also** is an adverb.
Adverbs stick to the verb.

The ways to put an adverb are the following: after the correct form of the **be**, before the verb when there's no **be.**

> - This man is **also** called 'the bird.'
> - This man **also** calls himself as 'the bird.'

Comment: Don't forget that some adverbs can be quite separated from their verbs. E.g., "He _drove_ [verb] his battered old car _dangerously_ [adverb]."

Comment: Yes, those are special cases. I highlighted the common uses.